# several development container environment with git

Tags: git, docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, git-submodules

I am using vs-code [devcontainer](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers) feature to create a containerized development environment of the following setup:

```
root_folder (main git repository)
|- .git
|- docker-compose.yml
|- @myapi-submodule (django python API)
  |- .devcontainer.json
|- @myclient-submodule (react js client)
  |- .devcontainer.json
```

In the `docker-compose.yml` I create 2 services respectively `api` and `client` and mount their corresponding submodule folder.

I can then "Open Folder in Container..." in 2 separate windows and everything works great except for git. I need to be able to make changes, commit them change branches... from the container but since only the submodule folder is mounted I can't use git at all.

What are my options in this scenario ? How can I modify the submodule from the container without the parent folder ?

Comment: DId you find a solution for this? You could just use git from outside of vs code, I guess, using eg 'Git bash' in the root project folder on windows...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to create a single .devcontainer directory in your root project dir and in there create a new docker-compose.yml (or extend the existing one if possible.

```
├── .git
├── .devcontainer
│   ├── devcontainer.json
│   ├── docker-compose-extend.yml # either extend current docker-compose file
│   ├── docker-compose.yml # or create a new one
│   └── Dockerfile # your new docker-compose.yml can also use different Dockerfile(s)
├── @myapi-submodule (django python API)
└── @myclient-submodule (react js client)
```

The `devcontainer.json` file should now use the new docker-compose file. You should also consider adding the .devcontainer directory to `gitignore`

Comment: You should not add `.devcontainer` to `.gitignore`. What's the point in automating the creation of your development environment if you then do not treat your code as code?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to solve this problem, you need to add the .git folder from the main repo as a mount like this:

devcontainer.json:

```
{
    "name": "Node.js",
    ...
    "mounts": [
        "source=${localWorkspaceFolder}/../.git,target=/workspaces/.git,type=bind,consistency=cached"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Just a head's up for anyone that follows... this will also cause any tracked files outside of the `${localWorkspaceFolder}` to be marked as `Deleted` in git.